# Query/scope not including unsaved records in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

**Scenario**: I have a quiz type setup where `Questions` have many `Answers` and also have a `Response` provided by the user (omitted).  A `response` has a `selected` attribute to indicate the user's choice and a `correct?` method that compares `selected` with the `correct_answer`.

**Code**: is here in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/codecarson/rails-unsaved-assoc-count), along with seed data.  Quick links to:

- [Question.rb](https://github.com/codecarson/rails-unsaved-assoc-count/blob/master/app/models/question.rb)
- [Answer.rb](https://github.com/codecarson/rails-unsaved-assoc-count/blob/master/app/models/answer.rb)
- [Response.rb](https://github.com/codecarson/rails-unsaved-assoc-count/blob/master/app/models/response.rb)

**Problem**: I want to return all responses for a question that are correct however, unsaved records are not included.

I've tried a couple of different ways, as you'll see in the code including scope,  `question.correct_responses` and also `inverse_of` (which I've read is supposed to be automatic now) - but to no avail.

Basically, I'm expecting following code to return 1, not 0.

```
q=Question.first
r=q.responses.build
r.selected = q.correct_answer
q.responses.correct.size # => 0??!  wtf man!?
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `scope` you're going to the database.

Since you aren't saving the response, you don't want to go to the database. Instead, you should use something like the line below, which will select all of the question's "correct" responses and then count them.

```
q.responses.select { |r| r.correct? }.size
```

**EDIT:** or the short syntax for `select`:

```
q.responses.select(&:correct?).size
```